# Changing Asp.net MVC app name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

What is the fastest/easiest way to do this? I don't want to recreate an application and I'm constantly needing to do this (Having hard time settling on a good name for my projects). What I've been doing it changing the name in the solution explorer and than closing the app. Than from there changing the name of the folders that the app is in, however when I go to reopen the solution has issues opening the MVC Project (still points to the previous name of the app & folder name). What am I not changing to prevent this and what could I be doing better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep your name consistent throughout everything, the easiest would probably be a global textfile search-and-replace outside of Visual Studio, using a regular text editor. This will get your solution and project files, the things that regular refactoring will miss.

Something like Notepad++, or something similar would work well. You can do just your solution and project files, and other non-codefiles, from there - then a global search-and-replace of your code files from inside Visual Studio.

You'd have to manually rename the solution and project files and directories.

I find doing it with a text editor is safer than trying to do it all in Visual Studio, because you won't miss any of the funky little things like AssemblyInfo values, default namespaces, webservice references, things like that.

Comment: You can do a full find-and-replace using Visual Studio anyway - just point it at the folder containing your solution instead of using the "Entire Solution" or "Current Project" options. There's really no need for notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

Addition to above answers. Do not forget to rename the `Assembly name`.

Right Click at the project go to properties. In application tab, change the `Assembly name` and `Default namespace`. This is useful when you scaffold something in a project.

When I added new `.edmx` file, it would get old project name even though, I changed all the file names following above answers. Later found out, I had not changed the `assembly name.`

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I would just keep the name of the app the same until you are ready for deployment.

To address your problem, you can right click the Solution in the Solution Explorer window and rename it to whatever you want it to be. Then whatever sub-folders you need to rename can be done similarly. You will also need to go to any file within the solution and next to the namespace, you will want to highlight the old project/folder name and refactor. This will allow you to change all references through out the entire project.

You will still need to reopen the solution next time as the location that the project is pointed to has changed and thus Visual Studio doesn't know where to look.